# Cannot access Workgroup in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, workgroup

I have a relatively simple network that consists of a couple Windows 10 PCs,  Android devices and Raspberry Pis.  For some reason I cannot access the shares provided by the PIs from anything but the android devices.  It says they are in WORKGROUP (using Kodi) but they simply don't show up in the network browser under Windows 10.   This used to work perfectly.  Right now I have to use an android device to copy files from my windows PC to the PI share.   Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: Can you access the share if you just type in the UNC path directly?

Comment: Actually no.  I am clicking NETWORK through the browser/file explorer.   If I type the UNC (ie: \\Pi2) it doesn't show any shares.